# Drupal login/logout button

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to add a simple Login/Logout button to a Block footer:

```
<?php global $user;
if ($user->uid) {
print t("<div class='gts_footer_logout'><a href='/GTS_MANAGEMENT/user/logout'>LOG OUT</a></div>", array('@name' => $user->name));}
else
{
print t("<div class='gts_footer_login'><a href='/GTS_MANAGEMENT/user/'>LOG IN</a></div>");
}
?>
```

Everything works, but I don't like the url to be hardcoded, how can I change this?

Answer (score 4):

use the [l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/l/7) function:

```
l(t('logout'), 'user/logout')
l(t('login'), 'user')
```

EDIT:
By the way, you shouldn't put html strings in t() function, this is not translatable in drupal's administration